# Beautifulsoup tag - find_all successful but find failed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having a problem where soup.find_all for a specific tag h2 is successful but soup.find specifying the text fails.

I need to find the h2 tags with various text such as Introduction, Results etc as shown in the attached picture.

Can somebody please advise? Thank you.

```
print(soup.find_all('h2'))
[<h2 class="Heading">Abstract</h2>, 
<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" tabindex="-1">Introduction<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>, 
<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" tabindex="-1">Patients and methods<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>, 
<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" tabindex="-1">Results<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>, 
<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" tabindex="-1">Discussion<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>, 
<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" id="copyrightInformation" tabindex="-1">Copyright information<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>, 
<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" id="aboutarticle" tabindex="-1">About this article<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>, 
<h2 class="u-isVisuallyHidden">Article actions</h2>, <h2 class="u-h4 u-jsIsVisuallyHidden">Article contents</h2>, 
<h2 class="u-isVisuallyHidden">Cookies</h2>]

print(soup.find('h2', text='Introduction'))
None
```

Comment: Please show the HTML document you are using as the input. Thanks! More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup.find(lambda el: el.name == "h2" and "Introduction" in el.text)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I also need the h2 tags to be purely "Introduction", without it matching other strings such as "Introduction to the document" for instance. Beside adding a regex to strip the span tags, is there another way?

Comment: `soup.find(lambda el: el.name == "h2" and el.text == 'Introduction')`

Comment: Thanks. This is an excellent solution. How did this method solve the problem while using text="Introduction" as in the question didn't? It seems to me that both are looking for the text variable to be "Introduction".

Answer (score 1):

When we use `text/string` as filter, what happened under the hood is we use `tag.string` to get the text and compare with the filter, in this case:

```
import bs4

html = '''<h2 class="Heading" data-role="collapsible-handle" tabindex="-1">Introduction<span class="section-icon"></span></h2>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.h2.string)
```

out:

```
None
```

Why the string return `None`:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what
>   .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None:

the `h2` tag contains the `span` tag with empty text, it's confused and will return `None`

@Thomas Lehoux 's answer is right approach.

This is BS3 API:

```
findNextSiblings(name, attrs, text, limit, **kwargs)
```

This is BS4 API:

```
find_next_siblings(name, attrs, string, limit, **kwargs)
```

you will notice that the old one use `text`, the current one use `string`, but they all the same, they all use `tag.string` to get value, you can use both of them. BS4 just sport the old format, that's all.

I can not find any `tag.text` API in both version, but it acts like `tag.get_text()`, it concatenate all the text under the tag.

in you case:

```
soup.h2.string    >>>  None
soup.h2.text      >>>  Introduction
soup.h2.get_text()>>>  Introduction
```

In short:

```
text in filter is tag.string
text in tag itself is tag.text
```

I think you use `find(string='  ')` in practice, it's less confusing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it would be confused by the span tag. Yes I think @Thomas Lehoux's approach gets close. But I want h2 tags where the string is purely "Introduction". Beside adding a regex to strip the span tags, is there another way?

Comment: @Michael Lam `soup.find(lambda el: el.name == "h2" and el.text=="Introduction").text`, because span tag's text is empty, text will return the exact the string of h2 tag

Comment: Why does passing in a lambda function with text=="Introduction" work differently from using .find("h2", text="Introduction")?

Answer (score -1):

`text='Introduction'` searches for `navigable strings`, not `tags`

> From the docs:
>
> text is an argument that lets you search for NavigableString objects
>   instead of Tags

You should try :

```
print(soup.find(text='Introduction').parent)
```

Comment: "Introduction" text can be in any tag (in `span` for example).

Comment: The OP was not trying to search for tags with `text='Introduction'`, you must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: you are right about NavigableString, but in this case, it's `None` because of the `h2` tag contains another tag

Comment: Still a useful tip! I didn't realize that you could get the parent from a NavigableString (in restropect, that's what the "Navigable" means).